# How to render more than 99 tiles in a 2D engine

Tags: c++, 2d, game-engine

I have created my own 2D engine and instead of creating a traditional tile map, I've drawn a large image on a 16x16 grid and then exported out the tileset and tilemap. Because of this, I have a large amount of unique tiles. My problem is that my engine does not seem to correctly handle tiles with three digits in the tID.
[Here is an image of the Game Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11yVC.png).

I think my problem is somewhere in the map.cpp, but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Here is my tilemap:

```
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
00,00,00,00,00,01,02,03,04,00,06,07,08,09,00,00
00,00,00,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,00,00
00,00,31,21,22,23,24,25,26,23,27,28,29,30,00,00
00,00,32,33,22,23,24,25,26,23,27,28,23,34,00,00
00,00,35,36,22,23,24,25,26,23,27,28,23,37,38,00
39,40,41,42,22,43,44,45,46,47,48,28,23,49,50,51
52,53,54,55,22,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66
00,00,00,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,00
00,00,00,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,00,00
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,00,00,00,00,00
101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116
00,00,00,00,117,118,119,120,121,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
00,00,00,00,122,123,124,125,126,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Here is my map.cpp:

```
#include "map.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "ECS.h"
#include "Components.h"

//we will have manager object which is defined in Game.cpp
extern Manager manager;

//constructor. implementation of map.h
Map::Map(std::string tID, int ms, int ts) : texID(tID), mapScale(ms), tileSize(ts)
{
    scaledSize = ms * ts;
}

Map::~Map()
{

}

void Map::LoadMap(std::string path, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    char c;
    //object to store file we're loading
    std::fstream mapFile;
    mapFile.open(path);

    int srcX, srcY;

    //parse. loops to move-through size of file and make tile for each character
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        //for each column, we'll move thru file
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            mapFile.get(c);
            srcY = atoi(&c) * tileSize;
            mapFile.get(c);
            srcX = atoi(&c) * tileSize;
            //convert char to int
            //scale up to 64x64
            AddTile(srcX, srcY, x * scaledSize, y * scaledSize);
            //skip comma
            mapFile.ignore();
        }
    }

    mapFile.ignore();

    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            //checks mapFile to see if collider layer is 1 or 0
            mapFile.get(c);
            if (c == '1')
            {
                //add collider
                auto& tcol(manager.addEntity());
                tcol.addComponent<ColliderComponent>("terrain", x * scaledSize, y * scaledSize, scaledSize);
                tcol.addGroup(Game::groupColliders);
            }
            //if zero, we still should ignore
            mapFile.ignore();
        }
    }
    mapFile.close();
}

void Map::AddTile(int srcX, int srcY, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    auto& tile(manager.addEntity());
    tile.addComponent<TileComponent>(srcX, srcY, xpos, ypos, tileSize, mapScale, texID);
    tile.addGroup(Game::groupMap);
}
```

Snippets of my game.cpp that are relevant:

```
assets->AddTexture("terrain", "Assets/env_1.png");
map = new Map("terrain", 2, 32);
map->LoadMap("Assets/env_1.map", 16, 16);
```

Comment: I might be missing something but i seems that your code assumes two digits in the map file (first loop in LoadMap always calls `get` twice). Then you have a second loop which doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the mapfile.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, but for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y) <<< sizeY and sizeX are not initialized

Comment: @willll They're parameters to the `LoadMap` function. Both are initialised to 16.

Comment: `mapFile.get(c);` reads exactly one character from the file and turns it into an integer. Since the program reads 2 characters in the first loop, once you have 3 character entries, like 100, things go wrong. I can't wrap my head around what the program is supposed to be doing so I can't pitch a decent solution.

Comment: @john right, and mapFile.get(c); algo is wrong as you said

Comment: From the code I seem to understand that the numbers in the tilemap are coordinates, am I right?

Comment: I would guess that the OP is trying to adapt someone else's code without properly understanding it. If so they should admit as much (or tell me I'm wrong).

Comment: @john I have been trying to follow along with the tutorials here and expand upon the engine: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Fo-5vJcB4w). The second set of for loops are for collision detection. That is working correctly and isn't really relevant here. If mapFile.get(c); only gets one character at a time, the loop should be modified to accept three character entries? My assumption was that the first mapFile.get(c); was for srcY and the other was for srcX.

Comment: @OriginalWilson Since your input is could be two or three characters I would read the whole input into a string and then check whether you have two or three characters in your string. You can use `getline(mapfile, str, ',')` to read upto the next comma, the comma will be read but not included in `str` so there's no need for `ignore`. Be careful of the last entry on each line, because that doesn't have a trailing comma you'll need to read that with `getline(mapfile, str)`. I'm sure there's plenty of other ways to handle this as well.

Comment: @john so because `getline(mapFile, str, ',')` will return a string, can I then use something like `srcY = std::stoi(str) * tileSize;` to turn the values into integers before the `Add Tile()`?

Comment: @OriginalWilson Yep, seems reasonable,

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up putting inside my for-loop that works:

```
        //it's y, x. so 13 is y=1, x=3
        getline(mapFile, str, ',');
        int srcIndex = stoi(str);
        int srcY = (srcIndex / 10) * tileSize;
        int srcX = (srcIndex % 10) * tileSize;
        AddTile(srcX, srcY, x * scaledSize, y * scaledSize);
        //skip comma
        mapFile.ignore();
```